# Laravel get last record of each month of column A with SUM column B value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to get last record of each month of column `value` with SUM value of column `volume` in MySql db using Laravel 5.4, my db structure like:

```
id | volume | value | date
---+--------+-------+-----------
 1 | 5      |   2   | 2020-01-01
 2 | 1      |   3   | 2020-01-22
 3 | 1      |   3   | 2020-02-02
 4 | 3      |   1   | 2020-02-03
 5 | 2      |   4   | 2020-09-03
```

So what I need is
Out put:

```
SUM(volume) | value | date
------------+-------+------------
    6       |   3   | 2020-01-22
    4       |   1   | 2020-02-03
    2       |   4   | 2020-09-03
```

What i did:

```
$data = DomesticMarket::select(DB::raw('SUM(volume) AS "volume", CONCAT(YEAR(`date`), "-", MONTH(`date`)) AS mydate, value AS "value", YEAR(`date`) AS gy, MONTH(`date`) AS gm'))
        ->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])
        ->where('active', '1')
        ->groupBy('gy')
        ->groupBy('gm')
        ->groupBy('mydate')
        ->groupBy('value')
        ->orderBy('gy')
        ->orderBy('gm')
        ->get();
```

Please so me the best way to retrieve the result like that. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following on SQL Server - I believe it will work on mySQL - I'm not familiar with Laravel, however you may be able to adapt this query to your needs.  The key to it is the use of the Window function (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...)).  This lets you rank the rows for each month in the nested query in order of your date value (what happens if you have more than one record for a specific date??).

```
SELECT SUM(volume) [volume], MAX(CASE WHEN [row]=1 THEN value ELSE 0 END) [value], 
MAX(CASE WHEN [row]=1 THEN dt ELSE NULL END) [date]
FROM (
    SELECT volume, value, dt,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt) ORDER BY dt DESC) row
    FROM TestValues
) src
GROUP BY YEAR(dt), MONTH(dt)
ORDER BY [date]
```

The PARTITION BY splits your records into groups using "YEAR()" and "MONTH()".  The ORDER BY ensures the records are ranked from last to first (by [date]) in each group.  The outer query uses that rank ([row]=1) to get [value] and [date] value for the "Last" record in each month. So [row]=1 is the last record by [date] in each month.